# outdoor light fixtures not lighting properly

Tags: electrical, lighting, light-fixture

I have 2 outdoor wall lights that I noticed do not work.  One does not work at all and the other is extremely dim.  Seemed like a simple light bulb fix but I replaced with 3 different led light bulbs and none worked at all.  I checked my breaker box and gfci switches and seen no issues.
Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Have you measured the voltage at the fixtures with a multimeter? How about trying an incandescent bulb?

Comment: Yeah, ‘running home to mama’ and using incandescent bulbs clears up an amazing number of problems.  I’m not saying use them permanently; but if the problem *suddenly goes away with incandescent* that gives us some very clear next-steps.

Comment: have not tried incadescent bulb yet, will give that a try.  the existing led bulbs were working just fine until they stopped.